# How To Use Superfeedr in a iPhone App?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, rss, superfeedr

I have some data that comes in the form of a RSS feed that I need to deliver to the user as soon as possible (this could potentially save lives). I found [SuperFeedr](http://superfeedr.com) and I want to use it to deliver content in the form of a [push notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html). Has anyone used this in an app? Are there other services that I should use to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

So, Superfeedr offers mostly a **server API** which means that it won't send messages directly to phones or browsers.

However, you can plug the notifications you get from Superfeedr with a service like [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com/) and you'll be able to push RSS content notifiction to iphones!

Comment: So you can run server side code on Urban airship? Or is it built in...I'm obviously not familiar with servers and stuff...

Comment: It cannot directly run "on" urban airship (I doubt they allow anything like that), but it's fairly easy to integrate :)